# I am integrating PayU Hosted Checkout in reactJs app. How to get response from payu form?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am creating web application using react js. I want to integrate payment gateway in that.
I chose payu for payment gateway. In their docs they have given one html form to put in our code.

```
<body>
<form action='https://test.payu.in/_payment' method='post'>
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="JP***g" />
<input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="t6svtqtjRdl4ws" />
<input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value="iPhone" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="test@gmail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="Ashish" />
<input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="Kumar" />
<input type="hidden" name="surl" value="https://apiplayground-response.herokuapp.com/" />
<input type="hidden" name="furl" value="https://apiplayground-response.herokuapp.com/" />
<input type="hidden" name="phone" value="9988776655” />
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="eabec285da28fd0e3054d41a4d24fe9f7599c9d0b66646f7a9984303fd6124044b6206daf831e9a8bda28a6200d318293a13d6c193109b60bd4b4f8b09c90972" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"> </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So, I simply put this form inside function component like this

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Payment() {
  return (
   <form action='https://test.payu.in/_payment' method='post'>
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="JP***g" />
<input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="t6svtqtjRdl4ws" />
<input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value="iPhone" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="test@gmail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="Ashish" />
<input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="Kumar" />
<input type="hidden" name="surl" value="https://website.com/success" />
<input type="hidden" name="furl" value="https://website.com/failure" />
<input type="hidden" name="phone" value="9988776655" />
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="eabec285da28fd0e3054d41a4d24fe9f7599c9d0b66646f7a9984303fd6124044b6206daf831e9a8bda28a6200d318293a13d6c193109b60bd4b4f8b09c90972" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"> </form> 
  )
}
```

it is working fine, but after getting payment done how to get response body in react component?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the answer yet? how to configure? It will help a lot if anyone has.

Also I have possible solutions:

1. **Bolt Method** (Popup Payment)
2. **PHP server** which accepts POST on .php file (I don't know PHP)
3. **Server to Server Callback** (asynchronous/don't know whether it will work)

- after payment, PayU POST to your server endpoint provided by you to update the transaction status
- once the status is updated the frontend can check the status by your product_no using new endpoint for verifyingPayment on your own server.

Here the catch is, you don't know which one will act first
a) Success/Failure URL redirect
or
b) Server to Server Callback for status update

If anyone has any better solution, i will surely appreciate it.